# ValueError: labels_true must be 1D?

Tags: python

How can I compute the performance of this algorithm. I tried this simple example :
`

```
 af = AffinityPropagation().fit(X)
 cluster_centers_indices = af.cluster_centers_indices_
 labels = af.labels_
 n_clusters_ = len(cluster_centers_indices)
 print("Homogeneity: %0.3f" % homogeneity_score(X, labels))
 print("Completeness: %0.3f" % metrics.completeness_score(X, labels))`
```

But i am getting the following error: ValueError: labels_true must be 1D: shape is (56, 52)
Please help!

Comment: Do you have a variable called 'labels_true'?

Comment: No i don't have §

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs due to the incorrect usage of `homogeneity_score`.

These metrics assume that the ground truth labels are available for your input data.

In your code, you have supplied the input data `X` and predicted labels called `labels` to the `homoegeneity_score` function. The correct usage would be:

`homogeneity_score(labels_true, labels_pred)`

where `labels_pred` in your case would be the `labels` variable. And `labels_true` should be the ground truth labels that you should have to be able to use the metric.

The same is the case with `completeness_score`.

Refer to the official documentation for both these metrics here:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.homogeneity_score.html
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.completeness_score.html

Also, refer to this answer for a better understanding on evaluation of clustering algorithms: [Performance Analysis of Clustering Algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690706/performance-analysis-of-clustering-algorithms)

Comment: In my case then I cannot use the' homogeneity_score'??

Comment: If you have ground truth labels to compare your predictions with, then you can.